# Finding a proper word for this situation

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Normally, we can say the adjective form of 'exist' in a sentence like:

> In the presence of measurement techniques, we can use them in order to calculate a window size.

I would like to say like this: the **existing** measurement techniques can be used to calculate ....

What if there is no such techniques now ****but**** a new technique will be published in a year.

So, can I say like the following sentence to emphasize the new technique?

> the **upcoming** measurement technique will provides more quantitative results.

Does 'Upcoming' fit in this action?

Comment: This is just my opinion: if you want to say *existing*, say *existing*. If you want to say *new*, say *new*. *New* implies that no such thing existed before the new technique. If you want to make it sound academic, you can use "A novel (measurement) technique".

Comment: you are actually right, sounds good. Sometimes we need to think simply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"What if there is no such techniques now but a new technique **will be** published in a year."*

Clearly, it's [upcoming](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upcoming) or [forthcoming](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forthcoming). The *latest* may not work as it's again existing *(the most recently existing!)*.

*Upcoming technology* is quite commonly used by techies. This may refer to the technology which is already made/discovered, but it's just coming in near future.

You guessed it right. IMO, it's upcoming (or forthcoming)

Answer (score 2):

‘Anticipated’ might work.  I think there needs to be a bit more elaboration, like this:

> A measurement technique currently under development should be able to provide more qualitative results.
>
> A measurement technique which we anticipate will be available within a year should provide more qualitative results.

Comment: This is good, although I would argue that these phrases go together. "We anticipate" would normally be used in a separate sentence after "under development". *A new technique currently under development should be able to do that for you. We anticipate releasing it by third quarter this year.*

Comment: Also good!  But it would depend on how much space the writer wants to devote to the new technique at this point in the text.  If it has already been mentioned, 'new' might be enough (not sure about 'upcoming.')

Comment: That's true in short written communication. In a spoken news report, or a full news article, I would expect them to use both sentences. You're correct, though, that a short note of the form "a spokesperson for ACME today stated..." would probably omit the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to say.

If the point of the document you are writing is to discuss and explain these new measurement techniques, or to make clear that present measurement techniques will not do the job but that measurement techniques in the future will, then you probably want to spell this out with a full phrase or even several sentences. Like, "Present measurement techniques will not ... but the new techniques that are presently being developed at Muppet Labs will ..."

If the present versus future is a trivial side issue -- or if you're deliberately trying to downplay because you're trying to fool the reader without actually lying :-) -- then as others suggest, you could simply say "anticipated measuring techniques" or "future" or "upcoming" or "new".

Answer (score -1):

How about:

> *The **planned** measurement technique will provide more quantitative
>   results.*

or

> *The measurement technique **under development** will provide more
>   quantitative results.*

?